# Losing Rankings Of Top Pages After Adding New Property To GSC

Tags: seo

Have you experienced some of your pages disappearing in rankings right after adding a new property in GSC?

In GSC I am getting the notification that 'Duplicate, submitted URL not seleected as canonical'.

Of course the pages affected by this are in my Top 5 traffic producing pages.

I believe it happened when I added the non-www version of the website as a new property in GSC. Anyone run into this problem and find a fix? [image]

Comment: It looks like your user declared canonical doesn't have the `www.`  Are using canonical meta tags or submitting a sitemap with the non-www property?

Comment: Have you added it as a Domain Property? Adding it as a separate www or non-www would likely require some additional setup, like setting a preferred domain.